# Adding multiple records for one thing in php

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a table called `paper`, which holds all the information for each paper that a user uploads to my system. I also have a table called `paper_topics`; this is meant to hold the `paper_id` and its `topic_id` from a table called `topic`. However I'm not sure how I can use PHP to allow the user to select multiple topics and then submit them along with the `paper_id` to the `paper_topics` table.

Here is the code I have for uploading the paper.

```
if(!is_dir("paper")) {
mkdir("paper");

}
function savedata(){
    global $_FILES, $_POST, $putItAt;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `internetcoursework`.`paper` (
    `paper_id`, 
    `username`,
    `title`, 
    `abstract`, 
    `filelocation`, 
    `date_added`) 
    VALUES (NULL,'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' , '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['abstract'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($putItAt)."', CURDATE());";
    mysql_query($sql);

    }
$putItAt = "paper/".basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FIleS['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$putItAt)) {
savedata();
header("location: listfiles.php");
echo "you have succesfully uploaded";

}else { 
if(copy($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$putItAt)) {
savedata();
    header("location: listfiles.php");
    } else {
        echo "you totally failed";

        }
        }


?>
'
```

Comment: You don't need to make `$_FILES` or `$_POST` global in `savedata()`. And why don't you just pass `$putItAt` as a parameter? You should also indent your code.

Comment: Assuming the upload succeeded is going to bite you in the rump at some point. There should be a `if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)` type check in there somewhere BEFORE you do anything with the file. You've also got no collision detection and will happily overwrite any file that was already on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly ("select multiple topics and then submit them along with the paper_id to the paper_topics table") the basic idea is to add a multi select form element to your form (like this http://onlinetools.org/tricks/using_multiple_select.php), then use that posted value to insert rows into the paper_topics table.  You'll need to insert the paper and get the paper id first ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php )

Does that answer your question?